# MySQL, split a string into all possible sub strings

Tags: php, mysql

Please see the details of this question: [phrase split algorithm in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787038/phrase-split-algorithm-in-php)

I want to do something similar to this question, but in MySQL instead of PHP...

I have a string in a table:

```
SELECT `string` FROM `strings`;

----------------------
        string
----------------------
"Today is a great day"
----------------------
```

What I want to do is this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `phrases`
SELECT `phrase` FROM (.. All possible phrases in table `strings`)
```

And then I'd be left with this temporary table:

```
SELECT `phrase` FROM `phrases`;

-------------------------------
             phrase
-------------------------------
today
today is
today is a
today is a great
today is a great day
is
is a
is a great
is a great day
a
a great
a great day
great
great day
day
-------------------------------
```

So basically the same as the question I referenced but in MySQL.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this on the database side?

Comment: why wouldn't you take the results of the PHP implementation and push the into the database?

Comment: I'm dealing with a lot of rows.It's slow to get the data out of the database and then put it back in again. The original strings are already in the database, and I want to get the new sub strings into the database aswell, so doing it all in the db will cut out the transfer.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using fulltext searches instead?

Comment: @Kenaniah: Thanks for your comment, I didn't realize fulltext searches would help with this. I've managed to solve my problem with PHP alone now, but it may benefit others if you post an answer using fulltext.